# How fast can I get mutalisks as Zerg and what's the build order to get there?

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-zerg, sc2-build-order

What's the earliest time (as in exact timing of how long it takes) a Zerg player can have mutas, and the build order to pull this stunt?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Is this a team game where another player can send you resources, or are you asking how long it would take you with no support from allies?

Comment: on my own, no support, otherwise its too easy!

Comment: If you're looking for something more viable than just the earliest time you can possibly get a mutalisk, I recommend you get 2 spine crawlers and send a pair of zerglings to scout ASAP. It sets you back a few seconds on the mutalisk, but you're much more capable of defending yourself, and you get to see what your opponent is doing at around 2:30 instead of not seeing them until 6:30 (at which point they may have plenty of towers, thus making your mutas completely pointless. This way you could shift to a different strategy.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a very detailed build whipped up that gets 5 Mutalisks @ **6:36**. It's possible there is a slightly faster build for 5 muta, but this will do. As said by other users, *I would not recommend this build as it leaves you open to attack* for over 6 minutes. If your opponents scouts you once, you will probably die... Might be viable on certain team maps though.

**EDIT:** I removed the previous 4 Muta build I had because, even though it's faster, anything less than 5 Mutas is *worthless*. 5 Mutas is the magic number needed to one shot your opponent's workers. If you only have 3 or 4 Mutas you will not be able to adequately harass your opponent, so it's better to wait for 5.

- 10  SpawningPool
- 10  Extractor
- 9  Overlord
- 10  +1 Drone on gas
- 10  +1 Drone on gas
- 13  +1 Drone on gas
- 14  Extractor
- 14  Lair
- 14  +1 Drone on gas
- 14  +1 Drone on gas
- 14  +1 Drone on gas
- 15  Overlord
- 15  Spire
- 14  Queen
- 16  +1 Drone on minerals
- 16  5x Mutalisk

In general, you should always get metabolic boost(speed zerglings) before going Lair tech. That said, here is a build (popularized by idra) that I would recommend using:

- 9 Overlord
- 14 Extractor (3 Drones asap)
- 14 Spawning Pool
- 15 Overlord
- 16 Queen
- (@100 ) Metabolic Boost (Remove 2 drones from gas) *
- 18 2 pairs of Zerglings
- 20 Hatchery (3 drones on gas)
- (@100% Queen) Queen
- 24 Overlord
- (@100 ) Lair, Gas
- (@100% Lair) Spire
- (@100 ) Overseer

This build sets you up with a good economy and allows for any necessary defense or early pressure.

Answer (score 14):

So there is an [8 Minute Mutalisk](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mIi22vr0gZc) strategy which does leave you sort of capable of defending yourself until your boys are in the air.  There are rumors of a 6:30 Mutalisk strategy, but you're cutting everything from defense to drones.

Both of these builds are pretty bad; and I think its important to discuss why they are so very bad and why you should never do them.

Mutalisks are a fairly high tech unit.  In addition to requiring heavy gas, they also require a Lair and a Spire, both of which are Gas heavy and have long build times (not to mention the Queen problem).  Even if your opponent doesn't harass you in that time, the normal timing pushes tend to be around 6 minutes.  This means that even if you do get your first couple Mutalisks in the air, chances are he's got a strong enough force to just roll you.

Strong Mutalisk builds (ie. not these) usually revolve around having 2 Bases.  However, for earlier Mutalisks (6:30) you need to skip that second Hatchery.  This means you won't have the production possible to bring about a strong Muta ball, or the resources possible to expand to get to that point.

Finally, you don't see Protoss looking for "Fastest Colossus Possible" builds, because a Colossus requires good Gateway support.  Likewise, Mutalisk need strong ground support.  The Mutalisk itself is design for hit and run tactics.  If your opponent pushes out with a strong MMM or Gateway units, you're going to collapse, and your Muta won't be cost effective.

I realize my trying to dissuade you may seem a little odd since you didn't ask that, but rather how.  However, I feel like this question is similar to asking: `How can I stick a Fork in a light socket`.  If you know enough that it isn't dangerous for you, then you know enough to figure it out on your own.

Comment: @Tzenes These are very good points.  In 1on1 I agree that an 8 minute mutalisk strategy really isn't worth the risk, however in a team game with a strong turtling partner in a shared base a fast mutalisk build can be a very strong strategy.

Comment: If there is a very long post, I don't need to scroll down to see it's yours -- you always start them with "so" :)

Comment: @juan bad habit I pi cked up from my coworker

Comment: @tzenes thanks for your answer, useful as usual - however you're (knowingly) off the point this time. I 1) asked time to be prepared if someone does it against me and 2) asked how so that I know how to counter it.

Comment: @John If someone does it against you and you are struggling the issue is not their build its yours.  Any "normal" build easily counters Mutalisk rush with little to no effort.  I pointing out the flaws in Mutalisk rush not just so you'd avoid the build but also so you'd feel confident in countering it.  If you don't feel that whatever build you're doing counters it, then the problem isn't Mutalisks, its your execution or your build choice.

Comment: @tzenes I agree with thwat you say and indeed your answer is much appreciated (and upvoted) ... but it's not fully answering the question as the one marked as answer (I was asking for build order). Also I feel this is an option when playing 2vs2 so the analogy of the fork in a light socket is probably limited to 1vs1? :)

Comment: @John a 2v2 strategy would require syntonization and would very based the map so I don't think you asked the right question if you were seeking that (not to mention 2v2 is broken in many peoples opinion). I'm ok with you preferring another answer I am only concerned it's not addressing your real problem. Many times players will ask: 'what should I do against X' when they should ask 'what am I doing wrong?'

Comment: @tzenes I understand your point of view, and share your thoughts on 2vs2. I might've phrased my question better but I mainly wanted to know how quick someone could get mutas (exact timing) and how would they go about doing that (build order), plain and simple. I din't give any 'I am getting hammered by mutas, I wanna do it too' angle to the thing. In this sense, the rest of the considerations are all very welcome and appreciated, but subject to your own interpretation of my question and not answering the question itself.

Comment: @John I'm not trying to give you a hard time, just trying to help.

Comment: @tzenes appreciate that, just hope you see my point too.

Comment: @john not really sorry. Why do you want to know?

Comment: @tzenes I asked how long it would take and how to do it, and you lectured me about why I wanted to know it and basically told me to figure it out myself if I really wanted to do such a stupid thing. Even if I share most of your opinions you basically did not answer the question, that is my point. Wrt why I wanted to know, even if it's not really relevant, just wanted to have a reference if I ever wanna try it out on 2vs2 or have a reference for the earliest time I can expect a muta attack. Try to remember that not all the players are as experienced as you seem to be.

Comment: @John I realize that it doesn't answer the question you actually asked, but by the same measure it does answer the question you should have asked.  Often times players will ask a question based on their limited knowledge, and its the wrong question to ask.  I have additional information, which if you knew you'd ask a different question; as a result I'm trying to share that information with you so that you know the question you should be asking.

Comment: @tzenes so you're basically saying no-one should ever ask a build orders for doing X and how long it takes to do it? LOL - I am pretty sure I know which question I wanted to ask at the time (based on my lack on information of the answer ergo experience in the game). If I already knew the answer I wouldn't have asked. Asking the question that you think I should've asked implies knowledge I was missing, so I couldn't have asked it in the 1st place. Thanks for enlightening me with such knowledge. We're falling a bit into tautology here :)

Comment: @John I agree that this is becoming circular in nature, not knowing what you don't know is tough.  I think the answer I gave is correct because it provides enough knowledge for you to know what you don't know, and then to understand that too.  Does this mean you shouldn't ask for BO? Of course not, but the right answer to asking, how do I go 1:1:1 as Protoss might be: you don't because its too Gas heavy.

Answer (score 3):

There are two main limiting factors for Mutalisks:

1. The build time of the tech tree (Spawning Pool, Lair, Spire) which takes 65+80+100 = 245 seconds.
2. The amount of gas needed for the tech buildings and the Mutalisks, 100 for Lair, 200 for Spire and 100 for each Mutalisk. That's a lot of gas that needs to be mined.

I did some experimenting and the fastest rush to Mutalisks you get out of this is the following:

```
    Drone x3
 9  Extractor (3 Drones mining gas as soon as finished)
    Drone
 9  Spawning Pool
    Drone x2
10  Lair
10  Overlord
    Drone x3
13  Spire
    Drone
13  Extractor (3 Drones mining gas as soon as finished)
    Drone x3
15  Overlord
    Mutalisk x3
```

Here the first three Mutalisks hatch at around 6:07 (Probably even a few seconds faster with perfect execution).

The build order fits together quite nicely and from the point where you start your Spawning Pool there aren't any delays where you have to wait for resources. So with this Spawning Pool timing this is the fastest way possible to get Mutas, and you even get three of them. You are also in a position to continue producing them as fast as gas comes in from your two geysers while getting more drones.

For purely scientific purposes you could tech even faster by starting your Spawning Pool one drone earlier. But to get the tech buildings up fast you'd need to cut a lot of Drones on the way, ending up with no economy and only a single Mutalisk that comes out something like five seconds earlier than the three in the other variant.